# binary text file decoder

Tags: java, binary, binaryfiles, decoder

I have binary file (text). I want to decode with Java 8.

This is the screenshot of my binary file.

[image: my binary file]

When I read with FileInputStream, the output like;

```
Ñ@¬e'ÍMnmÚ?¹ú»?
Ô?Ù?
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's not a 'text fille', then.  The right-hand column shows what would be the text if it were ASCII-encoded.  It's evidently not UTF-8 not UTF-16; these are fairly obvious to the eyeball.  The first 16 bytes look like they're some sort of format identifier, so your best approach is to find out what they mean.  Do the letters 'CRHL' mean anything to you?

Comment: What is the extension of the file, i.e. the 3+ letters after `.` in the file name?